# See what cocoapods an app on the apple app store is using?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Do apps have to acknowledge open source libraries they are using?  I saw some apps that do and some don't.  I was wondering if there was a way to find out what cocoapods are being used in some apps I like (that are already published on the Apple app store)

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there is a universal way to tell if an app uses a third party library.

The lesser GPL license, for example, requires that you include information that you're using GPL code.

Whether the app must acknowledge a pariticular library depends on the licensing for that library. Our company tends to credit ALL the open source libraries we use as a professional courtesy.